# Derelict and GFW3

Tags: d, glfw, derelict3

I'm trying to get Derelict3 to work with GLFW3 on Ubuntu 12.10.

I've successfully built Derelict3 and glfw3 using DMD 2.061.
Imports and links work.

But it seems the API has changed since [this article](http://www.dsource.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=6231) was written since I (case insensitively) can't find any reference to `glfwOpenWindowHint` in neither

- Derelict3 (`git://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3.git`) nor
- GLFW3 (`git://github.com/elmindreda/glfw.git`)

And I can't find any other tutorials on using GLFW3.

Does anyone have an uptodate tutorial on how to use GLFW3 either in C or D?

Update: I guess the examples directory in glfw3 is a good start right?

Comment: I also found this example https://github.com/bjz/glfwvbo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explore derelict sources - https://github.com/aldacron/Derelict3/blob/master/import/derelict/glfw3/functions.d#L135 - here is ur function.

btw i'm not think glfw3 is stable enough, i has some unresolved externals even with glfw2 on windows(one example is glfwGetGLVersion) so i think it's more likely a glfw issue. glfw2 official site has D bindings(outdated) in their support.

concerning examples, yes with D it is always a good choice to start with examples provided by authors, D still rapidly grows and so on. also it is a good to start asking on dlang.org forum. and last note, dsource is quite outdated and most of development acivity migrated to github.

hope all this helps you.

Comment: "I also found this example github.com/bjz/glfwvbo."
looks fine, should work. also look at the deimos - it is "official"  collection of C header translations, there is glfw2 and glfw3 bindings, with this you should be able to test everything with old simple fixed-pipeline OpenGL

https://github.com/D-Programming-Deimos/glfw

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.glfw.org/wiki/Moving_from_GLFW_2_to_3

This was the best guide I could find to the API changes. Use this to translate from other code/tutorials.